# Excel formula if date is greater than another date

Tags: ex

I have trouble with a dates. Don’t understand that is going on with it, some are correct and some goes wrong. I have tried change formatting, different formulas still not working correct. 
=IF(MONTH($M$6)&YEAR($M$6)>MONTH(N3)&YEAR(N3),"ON Risk","Expired")

```
            | 4/2017  | 5/2017 | 6/2017  | 7/2017  | 8/2017 | 10/2017
      5/2017| ON Risk |Expired | Expired | Expired |Expired |ON Risk
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked. Actually I used the dates, as you did but I compared the cell it self, not the year and the month. Hope this is helpful?

[Please check the picture below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHeZf.png)